# <span> tag css style declaration inside <div> tag

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble doing the task below.

> "Please change the text color in the span tag in the third div tag to red. For this purpose, please use the identifier attribute by assigning it to the aforementioned div tag and then create an appropriate selector using the mentioned identifier."

I tried to do it like this but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```css
div span#red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="golden-background third" id="red">
  <---- id spank declaration inside div tag <h1>Nagłówek 1</h1>
    <p>
      To jest przykładowy <span>tekst...</span>
      <---- "tekst..." should be red </p>
        <p>
          Oto nasz odnośnik: <a href="http://www.pcz.pl" target="_blank">link</a>
        </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div#red span {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes it will work. I also done it like you did. Problem is that according to excercise - declaration of span must be inside <div>

Comment: sorry, i have fix this

Comment: try with #red after div in style

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, you should mark it as such. That way, people with similar problems see that answer first, and the question itself is marked as 'answered'. Oh, and the answerer receives +15 reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not targeting the span item on your CSS. You are targeting any `span` elements which have the id `#red`

To solve this you have to add the id red to your span element

```
<span id="red">Your Text</span>

#red {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I also done it like you did. Problem is that according to excercise - declaration of span must be somehow inside <div>